# Is it legal in USA (FL) to organise tournaments (any sport) among friends, each player putting some money, with 100% going to the winners as a prize?

Tags: united-states, florida, gambling, is-x-legal

Is it legal in USA to organize no-profit tournaments (any sport) among friends, with each player putting some money to play, and 100% of the total pot goes to the winner (and possibly second/third place) as a prize, with no profit for the organizer (unless he/she gets a prize cause of the ranking of course). I live in Florida and I am interested only in beach volleyball (2 versus 2), but I guess other people could be interested so a general answer might be preferred. Specific questions:

1. Does the amount of money matter? We would like to put $5-10 each, so really just for fun and to make it a little more competitive
2. Does it matter the number of persons involved (my case not more than 10-14 probably)?
3. Is there a difference if the tournaments are organized at a public location (e.g. beach), private location (my backyard), or other private/public locations (University campus, the backyard of a bar/restaurant, etc?)
4. I am interested in the Florida case, but is it a federal law or each state has their own regulations?

Comment: Hello, Millemila! This is more of a question about the law than about sports themselves. You could equally have asked about a tournament of chess or about video games, neither of which are sports as we mean on the site. Thus, I believe it is more suitable on Law Stack Exchange (which already has questions in a similar vein you may find helpful, if this is not answered quickly).

Comment: I only partially agree, video games and chess are not sports, I clearly mentioned sport. Leaving it the sport section would have helped a lot cause this is surely a matter which interests many people on that site. Plus they could have given advice themself based on their experience. Is there a way we can link this there? What if I write a similar question only for beach volleyball on the sport site and link this? I do not think that regulations for beach volleyball prizes are the same for chess, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Why do you think a game is not a game? Legally, there is no difference, unless you already know of laws that make one. Yes, you did mention a sport, but your question is about the law, not the sport itself. Asking about a specific sport will not change the answer in general (unless again, you know it will, so why the question).

Comment: Because paying to play board games and having a cash award if winning is usually categorized as gambling, while in some countries the same cash involvement with a physical sport I do not think it belongs to gambling, but I might be wrong.